# R function to rename multiple values

Tags: r, dataset, rename, data-cleaning

I have a dataset with food items, I need a function to format the different names of 1 fruit to one single name. For example, dataset has Red Apple, Dried Apple, Green Apple, I want all these to rename to Apple. There are many different types of food. I am new to R. I need a function that says rename value to Apple if it has Apple in it.

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: Please, provide a minimal reproducible example, see [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for:

```r
dat <- data.frame(fruit=c("Red Apple", "Dried Apple", "Green Apple", 
                          "Orange", "Dried Orange", "Pink Grapefruit", 
                          "White Grapefruit", "Pear"))

library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(stringr)
dat <- dat %>% 
  mutate(fruit_new = case_when(
    str_detect(fruit, "Apple") ~ "Apple", 
    str_detect(fruit, "Orange") ~ "Orange", 
    str_detect(fruit, "Grapefruit") ~ "Grapefruit", 
    TRUE ~ fruit))

dat
#>              fruit  fruit_new
#> 1        Red Apple      Apple
#> 2      Dried Apple      Apple
#> 3      Green Apple      Apple
#> 4           Orange     Orange
#> 5     Dried Orange     Orange
#> 6  Pink Grapefruit Grapefruit
#> 7 White Grapefruit Grapefruit
#> 8             Pear       Pear
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to show if you have some reproducible data. You can use `gsub` with a pattern that removes all the characters before the space in for example "Red Apple" to "Apple. You can use the following code:

```
items <- c("Red Apple", "Dried Apple", "Green Apple")
gsub(".* ", "", items)
```

Output:

```
[1] "Apple" "Apple" "Apple"
```

As you can see, it returns for all `Apple`.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```r
x <- c("Red Apple", "Dried Apple", "Green Apple", "Purple Grapes", "Green Grapes", "Banana")
fruit <- ".*(Apple|Grapes).*"

sub(fruit, "\\1", x)
# [1] "Apple"  "Apple"  "Apple"  "Grapes" "Grapes" "Banana"
```

You can add any other fruits you want to detect into `fruit`.